# Horizontal centering text over image via CSS

Tags: css, html, image, alignment

Consider the following html:

```
<div class="image">
    <img src="sample.png"/>
    <div class="text">
       Text of variable length
    </div>
</div>
```

Where:

```
.image {
    position:relative;
    text-align:center; // doesn't work as desired :(
}

.text {
    position:absolute;
    top:30px;
}
```

Can you please tell, if there is a way to horizontally align the text in the center of the `.image` div? I can't use the `left` property, since the length of the text is unknown and the `text-align` property doesn't work for the `.text` div :(

Thank you.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Try the following CSS:

```
.image {
    position:relative;
}

.text {
    left: 0;
    position:absolute;
    text-align:center;
    top: 30px;
    width: 100%
}
```

Comment: Just a variation of @MyHeadHurts link, hopefully to give you ideas of what can be done.

Comment: One can play with the following example:
http://jsbin.com/docoma/1/edit?html,css,output

Answer (score 13):

Try this:

```
.image {
    position:relative;
}

.text {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width:100%;    
    height:100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: If you use flex, why not just swap the order using `order` rather than using an absolute positioning hack

Answer (score 2):

First you need to float the `.image` element, in order to 'collapse' its block-level descendants to the width of the element, and then use `text-align` on the `.text` element:

```
.image {
    float: left;
}
.text {
    text-align: center;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/9ZfBd/).

Or you could simply give it a `display: inline-block`, which will allow it to have its block-level contents contained, and remain in the document flow:

```
.image {
    display: inline-block;
}
.text {
    text-align: center;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/9ZfBd/1/).

Answer (score 1):

Can you not use the image as the background image of the 'image' div using background-image: url('/yourUrl/'); and then rather than have your text in its own div simply place it in the image div and then apply text-align: center;

Answer (score 0):

Using Flex is a more"flexible" option :-)

```css
#countdown {
  font-size: 100px;
  z-index: 10;
}

#countdown-div {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

#bg-image {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div id="countdown-div">
    <h1 id="countdown">10</h1>
  </div>
  <img id="bg-image" src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/PKaxc9qp52MkavbkMnnbu0AZAGcqxJCoa7wIgtCmOr2e1x9ngdsteITX6x4JqDDFOhhdZmF79Ac5yevMGaUmcSaFnFYsHQtLPxHg56X_8PfP1fNkxMNXYd3EzhuCb3eJ2qQA">

</div>
```