# Text in picture

Tags: html, css

I am really struggling with getting a text in the middle of every picture.
My gallery has 50 pictures and each of them has a different size. This is my code but it doesn't work :/ could anyone help, please? All "sample" text should be in the middle of the.

html:

```
<div class="row"> 
<div class="column">

<img src="/artbook/1.jpg">
<p> sample </p>
<img src="/artbook/2.jpg">
<p> sample</p>
<img src="/artbook/3.jpg">
<p> sample</p>
<img src="/artbook/4.jpg">
<P> sample </p>
<img src="/artbook/5.jpg">
<P> sample </p>
</div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.column img {
 margin-top: 10px;
 vertical-align: middle;
 display: block;
 align-content: center;
 max-width: 250px;

.column p{
 position: absolute;
 text-align: center;
 z-index: 1;
```

Comment: I would switch your layout style to your images being backgrounds within a div element, and the placing the text within the div. You will need to use padding to create spacing, and set your backgrounds to use the background-size:cover

Comment: there must be easier way :(( thank you so much !!

Comment: Neither of your CSS styles are properly closed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Horizontal centering text over image via CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9209764/horizontal-centering-text-over-image-via-css)

Comment: I made another edit, to show different size images as an example

Answer (score 0):

Check it out.

First create a `holder` for your image and text. Give it `position:relative`.
Now, absolutely position your `p` element containing text relative to its `holder`. But extend your `p` to all sides with `top:0; bottom:0; left:0; right:0;`. Now `p` is occupying the whole `holder`. Just apply `display:flex;` to it and center the content with `justify-content:center; align-items:center`.

```css
.holder{
  position:relative;
  display:inline-block;
}
.holder:hover img{
  filter: brightness(100%);
}
.column img {
 filter: brightness(45%);
 margin-top: 10px;
 vertical-align: middle;
 display: block;
 align-content: center;
 max-width: 250px;
}
.column p{
 position: absolute;
 display:flex;
 justify-content:center;
 align-items:center;
 z-index: 1;
 top:0;
 bottom:0;
 left:0;
 right:0;
 }
```

```html
<div class="row"> 
<div class="column">
<div class='holder'>
<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x100">
<p> sample </p>
</div>
<div class='holder'>
<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
<p> sample </p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: yeah this works !! thank you ! altough I had hover on that .column img
now it doesnt work. any ideas ? i am really desprate :(

Comment: What would you like to happen on hover?? on the `.column img` ?

Comment: basically the image is gonna be with " filter: brightness(45%)" and when you put cursor on it it will go back to 100%

Comment: edited the code for you. check it. Use this `.holder:hover img` selector to apply the filter.

Comment: yeah it works but also the text gets lower brightness.

Comment: The text is not getting lower brightness. It is an illusion created by its background image. The text is on top of it. You need to apply `color:` to `p` accordingly.

Comment: ahh thank you so much ! you have no clue how much you helped !

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work using an outer div container. It also uses the translate function to properly center the text both vertically and horizontally according to the parent container. One thing to keep in mind is that when you want to position something according to the parent container then the parent container must also be relative or absolute.

Also, by default, a paragraph element has extra padding around it. You may prefer to use a div instead.

```css
.column div.outer {
     position: relative;
     display: inline-block;
}

.column img {
     margin-top: 10px;
     vertical-align: middle;
     align-content: center;
     max-width: 250px;
 }
 
.outer div{
     position: absolute;
     left: 50%;
     top: 50%;
     transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="row"> 
  <div class="column">
    <div class="outer">
      <img src="1.jpg">
      <div> sample1 </div>
    </div>
    <div class="outer">
      <img src="2.jpg">
      <div> sample2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="outer">
      <img src="3.jpg">
      <div> sample3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="outer">
      <img src="4.jpg">
      <div> sample4 </div>
    </div>
    <div class="outer">
      <img src="5.jpg">
      <div> sample5 </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```